# c++: compile time error on function call if condition not satisfied?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp, enable-if, static-polymorphism

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve. As such, it might look a bit silly but bear with me. Let's say I have

```
template<int i> 
class Class1{
foo(){cout<<"j is divisible by i, so we will hang out"<<endl;}
}
```

and a `class2` having a fixed `int j` variable: either templatized by such an int or having a member variable. I want `class2` instances to only be able to call `foo()` if they satisfy a certain condition, in this case I want to ensure that say `(j%i==0)`.

The best I can come up with it, is:

```
template<int i> 
class Class1{
    static const int intParam=i;
    template<bool true>
    foo(){cout<<"j is divisible by i, so we will hang out"<<endl;}
}
```

and then class 2 would call it like this:

```
foo<class1::intParam%j>()
```

which is not very nice. Is there a better way of doing this? I have seen '[std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)' which is kind of relevant, but I am not too sure.

if you want the bigger picture, This is a signal/delegate brokering mechanism. In a system, Task objects should be able to be served/requested by performer objects only if they match the role enums(`int i`) specified in the task. Essentially this is supposed to be enum-based design without dynamic polymorphism. Is there a better way of doing this in C++?

Comment: Have you tried `static_assert`?

Comment: @krzaq see my comment on the proposed answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert):

```
template<int i, int j> 
class Class1
{
  public:
  void foo()
  {
    static_assert(i % j == 0, "Message upon i % j == 0 being false");
    cout<<"j is divisible by i, so we will hang out"<<endl;
  }
};
```

And call it e.g.

```
Class1<42, 24> f; 
f.foo();
```

---

Update to comments, just add `j` as an extra template parameter for `foo()` then:

```
template<int i> 
class Class1
{
  public:
  template<int j>
  void foo()
  {
    static_assert(i % j == 0, "Message upon i % j == 0 being false");
    cout<<"j is divisible by i, so we will hang out"<<endl;
  }
};

int main() 
{
    Class1<42> f; 
    f.foo<24>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but that would give me the error inside the body of foo(), and I won't hit that until actually hitting compile. I am hoping for something that stops me from writing foo() to begin with in the editor.

Comment: also your example deviates from the example I described above. j doesn't belong to Class1.

Comment: @user4376555 That doesn't make much sense. What if I'm programming in notepad? Nothing would be considered an error until I would actually compile my file with the code. Until you compile it, the text doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: @user4376555 No but you can pass `j` to the class.

Comment: think of class1 as a singleton. it is not templatized by the client's `j`s.

Comment: @user4376555 Does `j` change during runtime? Then this is not possible. Otherwise, just move the template parameter out and add a const member `j` inside `Class1`.

Comment: no but different clients have calls to foo() with different values of j.

Comment: @user4376555 Updated my answer, is this what you need?

Comment: as for it not making sense, well I am hoping for something that would be as invalid as calling bar() on Class1. I want the editor to be able to highlight the `foo()` call it for me.

Comment: thanks. yeah essentially, but ideally I want the function call to be invalid altogether, as I explained above.

Comment: @user4376555: Sorry I was writing my answer while this conversation transpired.... you want to make it impossible to even *write* the invalid code before you hit compile? You need some kind of static analysis tool, likely provided by your IDE, which will essentially be "compiling" things in the background while you code, so that it can tell you your function call is invalid.

Comment: @AndyG exactly.

Comment: @user4376555 Yes, and that's editor-dependent. Code can't influence that.

Comment: thanks. I realize that. I was hoping I would be able to do some magic with the likes of enable_if so that the function definition would not exist if condition was not satisfied. I would be more than willing to change my design in order to make this happen.

Comment: @user4376555 That still requires templates. Usually when templates start getting involved the "background-syntax-checker" just gives up and let's the compiler itself decide what is and isn't valid.

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to other solutions, I'd recommend using SFINAE to enable of disable functions depending on a condition.

```
template<int i> 
struct Class1 {
    template<int j, std::enable_if_t<i % j == 0>* = 0> 
    void foo() {

    }
};
```

The advantage of this solution is that if there is other overloads for `foo()`, the compiler will try them instead of giving a hard error. As you can see at this [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09bde2e2b3f0021d), the error given by the compiler is that:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:12:24: error: no matching function for call to 'Class1<3>::foo()'
    Class1<3>{}.foo<2>();
                       ^
```

This means that the error happens in the user's code, not in your header, and that if there is an alternative function when this one didn't worked, the compiler will try other overloads­.

Comment: Thanks! was there not a way of doing with enable_if and not enable_if_t?

Comment: Yes. You can either use `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` or you can define your own alias `template<bool b, typename T = void> using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<b, T>::type;`. I'd recommend the alias because it makes everything more readable.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

What you're really asking for is to make *writing* the code be an error, and I'm sad to say that's not really possible. I don't think there's an IDE out there that will literally prevent you from writing invalid code. However, if you implement one of my solutions below (the compile-time ones), then a sufficiently advanced IDE will be able to provide you with information that the code you wrote is bad before you hit compile.

A compiler like Visual Studio will essentially be "compiling" things for you in the background, and then underline bad code (read: won't compile) with red squiggly lines.

### Compile-time checking answer below

You suggest a couple of possibilities for your `Class2` structure, so let's address each:

First we'll begin with your `Class1` essentially as you defined it:

```
template<int i> 
struct Class1{
// how to define a "foo" function that is only callable 
// if Class2's j is evenly divisble by i?
};
```

Your first possibility is that `Class2` has a templatized `j` parameter:

```
template<int j>
struct Class2
{
    //...
};
```

A good solution to this would be to template `Class1`'s `foo` method, and then include a [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert), which is a *compile-time* assertion. This works because `i` and `j` are known at compile time.

Now `Class1` looks like this:

```
template<int i> 
struct Class1{
   template<int j>
   void foo()
   {
       static_assert(j%i==0, "j is not evenly divisible by i");
       std::cout << "j is evenly divisble by i" << std::endl;
   }   
};
```

And `Class2` can call `foo` like this:

```
template<int j>
struct Class2
{
    void CallFoo()
    {
        Class1<2> c1;
        c1.foo<j>(); // works
        
        //Class1<3> c2;
        //c2.foo<2>(); // fails static assert  
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9412f306879d774)

The other possibility you mention is that `Class2` could have a member variable for `j`. You can accomplish this so long as that member variable is [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) (and also `static` as a result):

```
struct Class2
{
    static constexpr int j = 4;
    void CallFoo()
    {
        Class1<2> c1;
        c1.foo<j>(); // works
        
        //Class1<3> c2;
        //c2.foo<2>(); // fails static assert 
    }
};
```

`constexpr` defines a *compile-time* constant here. So the value is guaranteed to be known at compile-time and our `static_assert` will work.

If `j` is **not** `constexpr` then we cannot achieve our compile time assertions. At that point you're relegated to *run-time* exception handling:

```
template<int i> 
struct Class1{
   void foo(int j)
   {
       if (j%i != 0)
          throw std::invalid_argument("j is not evenly divisible by i");
       std::cout << "j is evenly divisble by i" << std::endl;
   }   
};

struct Class2
{
    int j = 4;
    void CallFoo()
    {
        Class1<2> c1;
        c1.foo(j); // works
        j = 3;
        c1.foo(j); // throws
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5df8f4eb46f3e897)

Comment: thanks. for your information, this is direction i'm trying to get to: https://github.com/ShahOdin/Broker/ I pulled a trick by creating a proxy class to get template classes from a map of the base classes. want to know how far I can extend this enum-based approach.